# A view of published and unpublished content by the current user

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

On my site a authorized user can create a content type called protocol. This can be saved as either published or unpublished by the user. I want to make a page containing a view called "My protocols" where the current user can go and view all the protocols which they are the author of, published and unpublished.

To do this I created the view "My protocols" with the Views module, which shows the protocols in an unformated list of teasers. I use the filters "Content: Type(=protocol)" and "(author) User:Current(Yes)". And for page settings I have :

```
Path:/my-protocols
Menu:Normal: My protocols
Access:Permission | View own unpublished content
```

I've tried varying the Access part with no succes.

And under people>permissions I have set to allow authorized users to: "View own unpublished content" and "Access content overview page" (and other stuff offcourse, but these the ones I taught might be related to my problem with Views)

When I try looking at the "My protocols" view logged in as a authorized user I can't get it to show unpublished content, and I have checked that this users has created content of the type protocol which is both published and unpublished. But when looking at the page when logged in as an administrator I see both published and unpublished content.

Is it for some reason not possible to do what I want to do? Or have I forgotten something? Or do I need to install some further module to do it?

Comment: Are you using any access restriction modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because views uses the node_access table to check node access rights, but unpublished nodes are removed from the node_access table. You may try disabling "SQL rewriting" in the "Query settings" of the view, under the "Advanced" section. Not sure if that is the solution though.

Comment: That did it actually. I'm a bit unsure about what the setting actually does though and worry somewhat about if this causes some kind of security risk. I'll read up on it though. Thanks for the help.